# Create one generic method that can access many different context database tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a bunch of methods with names like:

```
GetMonsterName
GetTreasureName
GetSpiritName
GetCharacterName
```

They all do pretty much the same thing...like this example:

```
public async Task<string> GetMonsterName(long id)
{
    var type = await _context.MonsterType.FindAsync(id);
    return type.Name;
}
```

I know you can use `<T>` for a generic return type, but is there a way to also pass in a generic type for the database table that I need to access?

so that I could use it like this?

```
var type = await _context.<WhateverDatabaseTable>.FindAsync(id);
```

So that I wouldn't need to write a new method everytime I wanted to get something from the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself usually use a generic data access class(repository like) to get rid of duplicate codes, a major EF function here is Set<> method which give us the table by entity generic param:

a simple example would be:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(long id) where T : class
{
    var item = await context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
    return item;
}
```

using this method would be like this:

```
var item = GetAsync<Partner>(123);
```

To get the Name prop, we should create a base class which all entities accept as supper class :

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

change the base class:

```
public class Device : Entity
```

and change our generic function to :

```
public async Task<string> GetAsync<T>(long id) where T : Entity
{
    var item = await context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
    return item.Name;
}
```

and finally get the name:

```
string deviceName = await GetNameAsync<Device>(1);
```

Comment: thanks but how would you use this? Like if I wanted to use it for a database table called MonsterType?

Comment: thanks but I need to get the 'Name' attribute from whatever object...like 'item.Name'